# If $H$ and $K$ are solvable subgroups of G with $H$ normal in $G$, then $HK$ is a solvable subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $H$ and $K$ are solvable subgroups of G with $H$ normal in $G$, then $HK$ is a solvable subgroup of $G$.

I know a group is solvable if and only if it has a solvable series. But I don't know how to construct the solvable series of $HK$.

Comment: @rschwieb ,thanks for your link, and I find my question is no false, the link you give to me have already solved my question. My question is found in book "Algebra" by Tomas W. Hungerford.

Comment: @rschwieb If you look that link you will find that answer there is a counterexample to the question posed rather than a proof!